# Count of All Possible Paths back to same origin

Tags: graph-theory, permutations, combinations

I want to count the total number of ways we can travel between multiple cities and come back to the same origin in given maximum steps $\mathtt{N}$.

For example, if I have 5 cities (A, B, C, D, E) and every city is connected to next one bidirectionally. So City A is connected to B and E. B is connected to city A and city C...

So for $\mathtt{N = }$ odd number,  we will have zero paths as we can't come back to $\mathtt{A}$ after traveling to any city.

For $\mathtt{N =2}$ we have

$ A\rightarrow B \rightarrow A\\$
$ A\rightarrow E \rightarrow A$

i.e. 2 ways.

For $\mathtt{N =3}$ we have zero ways

For $\mathtt{N =4}$ we have:

$ A\rightarrow B \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow A\\$
$ A\rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow B \rightarrow A\\$
$ A\rightarrow B \rightarrow A \rightarrow E \rightarrow A\\$
$ A\rightarrow E \rightarrow D \rightarrow E \rightarrow A\\$
$ A\rightarrow E \rightarrow A \rightarrow E \rightarrow A\\$
$ A\rightarrow E \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow A\\$

i.e. a total of 6 ways.

I was thinking if we can represent this relationship using some equation for

1. A fixed number of cities (5 cities).
2. $\mathtt{K}$ number of cities.

Thanks

Comment: For $N=5$ you have two paths.

Comment: You are interested in finding the number of closed walks in a graph starting from a given vertex, in fact, since all your vertices are 'the same' you are just interested in the number of closed walks, and then you can divide by the number of vertices. Such things can be found out from the spectra of the graph, which is well known in the case of the cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, we write the graph (which cities are connected to each other) as an [adjacency matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AdjacencyMatrix.html) $M$.  If we choose city $A$ to be represented by row/column $1$ in $M$, then $M^d[1,1]$ is the number of length-$d$ [walks](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Walk.html) from $A$ to $A$.

In the case of $C_5$, the numbers satisfy a linear recurrence:
$$a(n) = 5a(n-2) - 5a(n-4) + 2a(n-5)$$
as given by OEIS [A054877](http://oeis.org/A054877) and the sequence begins $$0, 2, 0, 6, 2, 20, 14, 70, 72, 254, 330, 948, 1430, \ldots$$
when $n \in \{1,2,\ldots\}$.

A comment there describes a general formula for length-$n$ closed walks on the $m$-cycle $C_m$ (but no reference is given):

> In general `a(n,m)=2^n/m*Sum(k,0,m-1,Cos(2Pi*k/m)^n)` counts closed walks of length `n` at a vertex of the cyclic graph on `m` nodes `C_m`. Here we have the case `m=5`. - Herbert Kociemba, May 31 2004

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the perfect info. Do you mind pointing out some references using adjacency matrix `closed walk` problems? Some academic proofs would be perfect.Thanks

Comment: Virtually any graph theory text has this.

Comment: For a particular reference to something that goes more in depth, Richard P Stnaley's 'Algebraic Combinatorics' is a good book.